# Is there a name for a torus-like shape where the major ring is elliptical but the cross section is circular?

Tags: geometry, terminology, conic-sections, 3d

When I google elliptical torus, I get lots of hits for an ellipse (as a cross-section) rotated through a circle. However, I don't see a mention of the converse - a circular cross-section "rotated" through an ellipse in order to give the greatest volume ( although that is slightly ambiguous - I think replacing "circular cross-section" with sphere removes the ambiguity).

More specifically, what would I call the 3D shape formed by a sphere whose center travels around an ellipse.

Or yet more specifically, the union of the volume of all spheres of the same radius whose centers lie on the same ellipse. (is there an equally precise but more succinct way to say this?).

Is there a general term for the shape made from all points at most X units away from any point in another shape? (eg, increasing thickness). Could I call it something like a "thickened" 3D ellipse?

If not, can I dub this shape a torusoid? :)

Comment: i would when inventing terminology try to be as easily modifiable as possible. Start by calling a torus a "circle-circle-torus" and then your construction is an "ellipse-circle-torus". If your writing a paper you can use an abbreviation "an EC-torus" to save space. The nice thing about this is that if you want to change the underlying curve later you can modify this syntax to generate the name.

Comment: As a rule of thumb if you can't easily find a name for a shape using Google or whatever it probably doesn't actually have any specific name.

Comment: @SuzuHirose sometimes there are constructs, like sheared elliptical pyramid. As "thickened" shapes are pretty common, eg in vector graphics, I had wondered if there was a similar term.

Comment: Are [Dupin cyclides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupin_cyclide) the kind of surfaces you are looking after ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't believe so. An ellipse has major and minor axis symmetry, if I understood correctly, an inversion whose XY coordinate isn't zero doesn't preserve both symmetries, and one whose XY coordinate is zero doesn't create an ellipse. However, you led me to the answer: it's a [pipe surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_surface) of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pipe surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_surface) appears to be the technical term for the "thickening" that I was asking about above.

Therefore, a fairly short name for this shape is "the pipe surface of an ellipse".